# onCreateOptionsMenu not called consistently on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-activity

I am encountering some kind of possible race condition.

I am using an options menu created by onCreateOptionsMenu() in my activity.

This has been working fine until recently.

On ICS (4.0.4) wifi tablet this works perfectly.  I get the options menu every time.  onCreateOptionsMenu() is called immediately following onStart() and the last Fragment's onActivityCreated() which is after onCreate().

On JB (4.2.2) 4g phone (software menu button) this fails whenever WiFi is active.  Turn off WiFi menu shows up.  Turn on WiFi no menu.  After onStart() no onCreateOptionMenu() gets called.

UDPATE:
After much testing this is not just related to wifi.  I can start the application many times on JB(4.2.2) and sometimes it will succeed and other times it will fail to call onCreateOptionsMenu().
As a nice side-effect when you try to start the app this many times then at some point the licensing will pop the "Application Not Licensed" error and you're stuck until you clear data from the Google Play Store app and sometimes having to restart the device. What a pain.

I've even tried putting setHasOptionsMenu(true) in my last fragment even though I don't change the options menu from the fragments just in order to try and force an invalidateOptionsMenu that would cause the onCreateOptionsMenu to get called but all to no avail.

There is definitely some race condition going on.  But logs show you nothing.

How can I force onCreateOptionsMenu() to get called consistently?

Comment: That is bizarre. What device is this?

Comment: It is a Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: @androidin What is your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: minSdk=15 targetSdk=20

Comment: @androidin You say software menu button... Do you mean in the nav bar, or on the action bar?

Comment: As opposed to a hardware menu button.

Comment: What kcoppock is asking is that there is no "options menu" in modern versions of Android. You use the action bar, which happens to still use `onCreateOptionsMenu()` for backwards compatibility purposes. We do not know if by "software menu button" you mean the action bar overflow ("..." in the action bar), the "legacy menu button of shame" ("..." in the nav bar), or something else.

Comment: For example, [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemoNative) displays the action bar contents, including the overflow, just fine on a Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.3, with WiFi off or on. Try that sample project; if it does not show you the action bar and overflow on your device, your device has issues (e.g., bad ROM mod). If the sample does work, please consider editing your question to show your manifest, your menu resource, and your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` implementation.

Comment: Got it.  Yes, I'm using the ActionBar with the ellipsis in the corner.  All menu items are in the overflow.

Comment: The sample app runs fine with wifi on or off.
But so did my app until recently after I added more features and triggered this race condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after much testing, this was all due to an async listener from In-App-Billing.
This listener would sometimes run early and sometimes run late.
There was code in the listener that made modifications to items on the options menu.
If the listener ran early enough the options menu was null and at some point the app would crash.
To fix the problem I made sure that the listener was not called until after the options menu was created.